# Accessing state from another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just learning React and ran into a problem. I have a selector allowing me to choose year/make/model of a vehicle. However, I want it to reset make and model if the year is changed, or just reset the model if make is changed, so that those options state is set back to null and thus in the ui deselected.

However, the problem is I don't know how to make the state of a component available to the others. I figured the solution could be as simple as using an onChange function for year, that will then take the state of make/model and reset to null, though that's not possible without year.js knowing the state of the other 2...

Hopefully you understand what I'm talking about. Here's the code.
Year.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../CSS/App.css';

const vehicleYear = [
    {id:1,label:"2019",href:"#"},
    {id:2,label:"2018",href:"#"},
    {id:3,label:"2017",href:"#"},
    {id:4,label:"2016",href:"#"},
    {id:5,label:"2015",href:"#"},
    {id:6,label:"2014",href:"#"}
];

class Year extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            year: null,
        }
    }

        createYearList = () => {
            let listItems = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < vehicleYear.length; i++) {
                listItems.push(
                    <li className={`list ${this.state.year === vehicleYear[i].id ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={(e) => {
                        this.yearClick(e, vehicleYear[i].id, vehicleYear[i].label)
                    }}>
                        <a href={vehicleYear[i].href}>{vehicleYear[i].label}</a>
                    </li>
                );
            }
            return listItems;
        };

        yearClick = (e, id, label) => {
            let state = this.state;
            state.year = id;
            this.setState(state);

            console.log(this.state);
            console.log(this.props.year);
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.createYearList()}
                </div>
            )
        }

}

export default Year;
```

Make.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../CSS/App.css';

const vehicleMake = [
    {id:1,label:"POLARIS",href:"#"},
    {id:2,label:"CAN_AM",href:"#"},
    {id:3,label:"YAMAHA",href:"#"},
    {id:4,label:"SUZUKI",href:"#"},
    {id:5,label:"ARCTIC-CAT",href:"#"}
];

class Make extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            make: null
        }
    }

    createMakeList = () => {
        let listItems = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < vehicleMake.length; i++){
            listItems.push(
                <li className={`list ${this.state.make === vehicleMake[i].id ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={(e)=>{this.makeClick(e, vehicleMake[i].id, vehicleMake[i].label)}}>
                    <a href={vehicleMake[i].href}>{vehicleMake[i].label}</a>
                </li>
            );
        }
        return listItems;
    };

    makeClick = (e, id, label) => {
        console.log(id, label);
        let state = this.state;
        state.make = id;
        this.setState(state);
        console.log(state.make);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.createMakeList()}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Make;
```

Model.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../CSS/App.css';

const vehicleModel = [
    {id:1,label:"RZR 570",href:"#"},
    {id:2,label:"RZR 900",href:"#"},
    {id:3,label:"RZR S 900",href:"#"},
    {id:4,label:"RZR S 1000",href:"#"},
    {id:5,label:"RZR S 1000 TURBO",href:"#"}
];

class Model extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            model: null
        }
    }

    createModelList = () => {
        let listItems = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < vehicleModel.length; i++){
            listItems.push(
                <li className={`list ${this.state.model === vehicleModel[i].id ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={(e)=>{this.modelClick(e, vehicleModel[i].id, vehicleModel[i].label)}}>
                    <a href={vehicleModel[i].href}>{vehicleModel[i].label}</a>
                </li>
            );
        }
        return listItems;
    };

    modelClick = (e, id, label) => {
        console.log(id, label);
        let state = this.state;
        state.model = id;
        this.setState(state);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.createModelList()}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Model;
```

And here's the main App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './CSS/App.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import rzrPic from './Media/rzr-xp-1000-eps-trails-rocks-media-location-1-xxs.jpg';
import camsoT4S from './Media/camso-atv-t4s.jpg';
import Year from './Components/Year';
import Make from './Components/Make';
import Model from './Components/Model';

class App extends Component {

    render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Container fluid="true">
              <Row>
                  <Col xs="3" className="categories">
                      <div>
                        <span className="categoryHeader">
                            <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                VEHICLE YEAR
                            </h2>
                        </span>
                        <div className="categoryList">
                            <ul>
                                <Year/>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <span className="categoryHeader">
                            <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                VEHICLE MAKE
                            </h2>
                        </span>
                          <div className="categoryList">
                              <ul>
                                  <Make/>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <span className="categoryHeader">
                            <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                VEHICLE MODEL
                            </h2>
                        </span>
                          <div className="categoryList">
                              <ul>
                                  <Model/>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="6" className="fill">
                      <img src={rzrPic} alt="rzr xp 1000"/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="3" className="categories">
                      <span className="categoryHeader2">
                          <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                              AVAILABLE TRACKS
                          </h2>
                      </span>
                      <div className="Track">
                          <img src={camsoT4S} alt="Camso T4S Tracks"/>
                          <div className="TrackInfo">
                              <h3>CAMSO T4S - 4 SEASON</h3>
                              <p>Starting at $3,999.00</p>
                              <span>
                                  ADD TO CART
                              </span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="Track">
                          <div className="TrackInfo">
                              <h3>CAMSO T4S - 4 SEASON</h3>
                              <p>Starting at $3,999.00</p>
                              <p className="select">SELECT</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Col>
              </Row>
          </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Instead of storing these states individually in their components, you would have to raise it to a common parent level

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the selected year / make / model in each component, store them in the parent `App`. You will then handle the reset logic in the `App` component.

Here is how to refactor your code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../CSS/App.css";

// The list of years is now passed as props
//
// const vehicleYear = [];

class Year extends Component {
  // You dont need the constructor anymore as the component
  // doesn't have a state to initialize
  //
  // constructor(props) {}

  createYearList = () => {
    // Use the year list passed as a prop from the parent
    const { vehicleYear } = this.props;

    let listItems = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < vehicleYear.length; i++) {
      listItems.push(
        <li
          className={`list ${
            this.state.year === vehicleYear[i].id ? "active" : ""
          }`}
          onClick={e => {
            this.yearClick(e, vehicleYear[i].id, vehicleYear[i].label);
          }}
        >
          <a href={vehicleYear[i].href}>{vehicleYear[i].label}</a>
        </li>
      );
    }
    return listItems;
  };

  yearClick = (e, id, label) => {
    // Call the onClick function passed as a prop from the parent
    this.props.onClick(e, id, label);
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createYearList()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Year;
```

I only modified the `Year` component since the `Make` and `Model` components have the same structure. I'll come back to this later.

And here is how to use `Year` in `App`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import ...

// Define the list of years
const vehicleYear = [
  {id:1,label:"2019",href:"#"},
  {id:2,label:"2018",href:"#"},
  {id:3,label:"2017",href:"#"},
  {id:4,label:"2016",href:"#"},
  {id:5,label:"2015",href:"#"},
  {id:6,label:"2014",href:"#"}
];

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // Initialise the state of the App component
        this.state = {
            year: null,
        }
    }

    // Move the click handler from the Year component to its parent component
    yearClick = (e, id, label) => {
      this.setState({
        year: id
      });
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <Container fluid="true">
                <Row>
                    <Col xs="3" className="categories">
                        <div>
                          <span className="categoryHeader">
                              <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                  VEHICLE YEAR
                              </h2>
                          </span>
                          <div className="categoryList">
                              <ul>
                                  {/* Pass the list of years, the selected year and the handler to 
                                  select a year to the Year component */}
                                  <Year vehicleYear={vehicleYear} selectedYear={this.state.year} onClick={this.yearClick} />
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        ...
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now you have a fully controled `Year` and the logic handled by the `App` component. If you want to reset the selected year, you only have to create and call such a function in the `App` component:

```
resetYear = () => {
  this.setState({
    year: null
  });
};
```

### Bonus: Refactoring

You can refacto your `Year`, `Make` and `Model` components to one reusable component because they have exactly the same structure. Here is a `ListComponent` extracted from them:

```
// The list components takes three arguments:
// - itemsList: items to be displayed
// - selectedItemId: the id of the selected item
// - onSelect: a function to call when an item is selected

class ListComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { itemsList, selectedItemId, onSelect } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {itemsList.map(item => (
          <li
            className={`list ${selectedItemId === item.id ? "active" : ""}`}
            onClick={e => {
              onSelect(e, item.id, item.label);
            }}
          >
            <a href={item.href}>{item.label}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListComponent;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<div>
  <span className="categoryHeader">
      <h2 className="categoryHeading">
          VEHICLE YEAR
      </h2>
  </span>
  <div className="categoryList">
      <ul>
          <ListComponent onSelect={this.selectYear} itemsList={vehicleYear} selectedItemId={this.state.year}/>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <span className="categoryHeader">
      <h2 className="categoryHeading">
          VEHICLE MAKE
      </h2>
  </span>
    <div className="categoryList">
        <ul>
            <ListComponent onSelect={this.selectMake} itemsList={vehicleMake} selectedItemId={this.state.make}/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
  <span className="categoryHeader">
      <h2 className="categoryHeading">
          VEHICLE MODEL
      </h2>
  </span>
    <div className="categoryList">
        <ul>
            <ListComponent onSelect={this.selectModel} itemsList={vehicleModel} selectedItemId={this.state.model}/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And this will be easy to use when adding database calls? I structured it the way I did because I intended those components to be reducers later on in production when integrated with drupal and rest api. This solution is great though! Thanks! Just need to know if I will be able to continue this structure later on.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to keep your state in the parent in this case in the App.js or create a component ad hoc to be the parent of your components, and simply pass a prop onChangeYear for example to change the state of your parent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './CSS/App.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import rzrPic from './Media/rzr-xp-1000-eps-trails-rocks-media-location-1-xxs.jpg';
import camsoT4S from './Media/camso-atv-t4s.jpg';
import Year from './Components/Year';
import Make from './Components/Make';
import Model from './Components/Model';

class App extends Component {
    contructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { year: "" }
    }


    render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Container fluid="true">
              <Row>
                  <Col xs="3" className="categories">
                      <div>
                        <span className="categoryHeader">
                            <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                VEHICLE YEAR
                            </h2>
                        </span>
                        <div className="categoryList">
                            <ul>
                                <Year onChangeYear={(year) => {this.setState({year})/>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <span className="categoryHeader">
                            <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                VEHICLE MAKE
                            </h2>
                        </span>
                          <div className="categoryList">
                              <ul>
                                  <Make/>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <span className="categoryHeader">
                            <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                                VEHICLE MODEL
                            </h2>
                        </span>
                          <div className="categoryList">
                              <ul>
                                  <Model/>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="6" className="fill">
                      <img src={rzrPic} alt="rzr xp 1000"/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="3" className="categories">
                      <span className="categoryHeader2">
                          <h2 className="categoryHeading">
                              AVAILABLE TRACKS
                          </h2>
                      </span>
                      <div className="Track">
                          <img src={camsoT4S} alt="Camso T4S Tracks"/>
                          <div className="TrackInfo">
                              <h3>CAMSO T4S - 4 SEASON</h3>
                              <p>Starting at $3,999.00</p>
                              <span>
                                  ADD TO CART
                              </span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="Track">
                          <div className="TrackInfo">
                              <h3>CAMSO T4S - 4 SEASON</h3>
                              <p>Starting at $3,999.00</p>
                              <p className="select">SELECT</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Col>
              </Row>
          </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you find yourself having a lot of components in your web app I would think to integrate Redux to handle the state globally https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started.